# Copy Cells With No Fill in Conditionally Formatted Column

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a VBA macro that searches filled cells within a conditionally formatted column, and selects only the cells that contain data but are not filled red by the conditional formatting (no fill color).

Then, once the cells with no fill have been selected, I would like to copy them to the bottom of a different column. I am stuck at selecting the unfilled cells within my range.

```
    Sub PM2_COPY()

    Sheets("M&C").Select
    range("A2").Select
    range(selection, selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    selection.COPY
    Sheets("SUMMARY").Select
    range("U7").Select
    selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    range("U6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(range( _
        "U6"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color _
        = RGB(255, 199, 206)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    range("U7").Select
    range.AutoFilter (cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone)
    For Each cell In range.AutoFilter(cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone)
    cell.Select
    selection.COPY
    Sheets("SUMMARY").Select
    range("A7").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Range.AutoFilter` and filter by color.

Comment: If you were to loop, then you need to use `cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex` for conditionally-formatted cells.

Comment: I apply a filter earlier in the code to sort them to the bottom, is this what you are referring to? I'm not sure how the range.autofilter function helps me here. When I put that into my code it gives me an "argument not optional error".

Comment: If you're already using a filter, then just filter by color, instead of sorting. I was referring to the [`Range.AutoFilter` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)... you would have to add the arguments. You can filter for cells that have no color, and then after that you can copy the visible cells.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) and specify cells with no color, then copy the visible cells. Something like the following:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("U6:U" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
        xlFilterNoFill

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim visibleCells As Range
    Set visibleCells = .Range("U7:U" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    .ShowAllData ' Clear filter

    If Not visibleCells Is Nothing Then
        visibleCells.Copy
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End With
```

Comment: lastRow = .Cells(.Row.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row is highlighted giving me an error that states "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: `.Rows.Count`, you've got a typo.